# Is the name of my table the issue? RODBC R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I am trying to pull data from a SQL server database using RODBC in R. All my connections are set up and work fine. The problems lies when I try to pull data from a table named Group. It seems that the name of the table is the problem since I am able to pull data from other tables. Perhaps the table name is a function/command. I was able to solve this problem in DBVizualizer by adding quotes in the table name however it doesn't work.

```
group1 <- sqlQuery(ch, paste("
  SELECT *
  from  asb.Group "))
```

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `Group` is a reserved word in many (most? all?) SQL DBMSes, so it must be escaped in some form. In most (all?) DBMSes, langtang's approach of `[Group]` should work, in others you may need to use double (not single) quotes instead, as in `asb."Group"`.

Comment: FYI, not sure if there's something else in your real code, but _here_ the `paste` is doing nothing for you. If you are really doing more where you think it is necessary, then be _very wary_ of pasting "data" into your questions: "accidental" [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
group1 <- sqlQuery(ch, "SELECT * from asb.[Group]")
```